# Make Vigenere Decipher case-insensitive in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vigenere

I am currently working on a school project where I need to build a decrypter for the Vigenere Cipher. The deciphering is working out just fine, but I have a problem which is that every letter is lowercase. I know the reason for this is that my used the casefold() method for my initial string. I did it so I can compare it to the alphabet a-z. Now here is my question: How can I modify the code in so that it will return the corresponding letter in uppercase?

```
def decipher(key):    
        original = "Rpoe, Xknf cne Rosvuhcl"
        string = original
        Alphabet ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        dec_message = ""
        key = key.lower()
        string = string.casefold()
        textlength = len(string)
        exp_key = key
        exp_key_length = len(exp_key)
        while exp_key_length < textlength:
            exp_key = exp_key + key
            exp_key_length = len(exp_key)
        key_position = 0
        for letter in string:
            if letter in Alphabet:
                position = Alphabet.find(letter)
                key_char = exp_key[key_position]
                key_char_position = Alphabet.find(key_char)
                key_position += 1 
                new_position = position - key_char_position
                if new_position > 26:
                    new_position = new_position + 26
                new_character = Alphabet[new_position]
                dec_message = dec_message + new_character
            else:
                dec_message = dec_message + letter
        print(dec_message)
        print(original)
        return(dec_message)
            
decipher("ABC")
```

I tried to use a for loop so I can look at each letter in the encrypted string and then .upper the letter at the corresponding position in the dec_message string, however, that didn´t work.
The encrypted text is: Rome, Wine and Portugal

Comment: By default the cipher loses case information, so you won't be able to retrieve it. You probably need to extend the alphabet (and cipher) to acommodate both cases for all letters.

Comment: Instead of `casefold()`-ing the entire string, you could check each letter inside the loop to see if it's `isupper()`, storing the result into a flag variable, and `lower()` it only then. And if the flag is set, `upper()` the `new_character` prior to appending it to the result.

Comment: @tevemadar I have tried using this approach as the other one wasn´t viable for thi. However, for some weird reason, it doesn´t return the letter as a lowercase. I have just implemented  if letter.isupper() == True:
               letter.lower() before the "if letter in Alphabet". This doesn´t make the letter lowercase tho, it still returns the same result. I haven´t used the flag variable yet as I wanted it to work before.

Comment: Generally speaking, Python methods for immutable objects will not change the object in place, but rather return a changed copy. So you need to assign the return value to overwrite the letter: `letter = letter.lower()`. See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower